# Proper model relationship for Player and Prizes?

Tags: python, django

I seem to have a mental impediment when it comes to abstracting model relationships.

I want to have prizes available to players. Not all players have prizes, but a list should be available if needed.

This is what I have so far:

```
class Prize(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="gifts", null=True, blank=True)
```

I should be able to do Profile.prizes and get a list if any exists, but ...

a) this is probably the wrong relationship
b) this is probably backwards...

I just need some slight adjustment to get back on track here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ManyToManyField` for `Player` model:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    prizes = models.ManyToManyField("Prize")


class Prize(models.Model):
    # prize_name = ...
    # prize_amount = ...
```

Then you can get all prizes for one specific player with:

```
player = Player.objects.get(id=12)
player.prizes.all()
```

For more information and examples about ManyToMany Relations, check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this way:

```
class Prize(models.Model):
    # write here prize model fields


class Player(models.Model):
    prizes = models.ManyToManyField(Prize, blank=True)
```

By using this approach, u can get all the prizes a player have,

```
player = Player.objects.get(id=123)
prizes = player.prizes.all()
```

and you can also find, how many players got any specific prize,

```
prize = Prize.objects.get(id=123)
players = prize.player_set.all()
```